# (Ubuntu) How to browse folder+subdirectories by filetype?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Assuming I have multiple subdirectories under "Music", and I want to view all the files ending in *.mp3

On Windows this is easy to do. How can I go about it in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu also has a search tool like Windows. Under **Places -> Search for Files** you can choose what folder to search and a part of the filename to search for. You can even use regular expressions in the search (In the dropdown of **Available Options**, choose **Matches regular expression**). Unless you enjoy naming non-mp3 files weird things like `myfile.mp3.txt`, then using **name contains** should be sufficient for the search:

[image]

If you would like to use the command line:

```
find ~/Music -type f -name "*.mp3"
```

Comment: yep I had figured out this much by myself, by thanks for the visual explanation